# Oracle Apex - Using AD authentication, can the username / password be inherited from Windows

Tags: oracle, authentication, oracle-apex

We are looking to introduce LDAP authentication to an existing Oracle Apex (Application Express 4.2.5) application to allow us to utilise active directory groups. Setting this up is fairly simple and works fine, however we have been asked if its possible to inherit the username / password from the users network login and pass this through the apex login so the user only has to login once. 
Is this possible?

Comment: Don't use the `apex` tag for `oracle-apex` questions.

Comment: LDAP authentication does just that, I'm not sure I understand the question http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2013/09/using-ldap-to-authenticate-your-apex.html

Comment: @scott - Sorry, I don't think I was clear. We have been asked if it is possible for the users to sign onto their machine and then Apex pick up the username/password, logging the user in automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think the term you're looking for is "Single sign on"

There is quite a bit of information on this out there, and I think it's changed a bit over time. Exact solution probably really depends on infrastructure factors.

https://www.slideshare.net/nielsdb/single-signon-for-apex-apps